# vue-router Route with name 'ROUTENAME' does not exist in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router

I have some routes which are newly added. the sidebar is dynamically created based on links added to the routes.

I am able to print the route name in plain text but when assigned to the `vue-route` it simple gives `localhost:8080` so where am i going wrong.

#### configroutes file:

```js
const routes = [
    {
        path: 'create_schedule',
        name: 'activate.create_schedule',
        meta: {
            _routeName: 'activate_create_schedule',
            sectionName: 'Create Schedule'
        },
        component: createSchedule,
    },

]
```

#### Main Routes File

```js
import ConfigureRoutes from './configureRoutes.js';

const routes = [
    ...ConfigureRoutes,
];

export default routes;

export const getActivateConfigRoutes = function () {
    return routes;
};
```

#### dashboard Component file

```js
data() {
            const configRoutes = getActivateConfigRoutes();

            const sidebarRoutes = [
                {
                    name: '/',
                    meta: {
                        sectionName: 'CONFIGURE'
                    },
                    redirect: {
                        name: 'activate.create_schedule'
                    },
                    children: [
                        ...configRoutes
                    ]
                },
];

            return {
                sidebarRoutes
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

#### aside bar:

```html
<aside class="menu">
        <ul class="menu-list --campaign-sidebar">
            <li class="main-section-menu" v-for="(sidebarRoute, index) in sidebarRoutes" :key="sidebarRoute.id">
                <router-link :to="{ name: sidebarRoute.name, params: { campaign_id: currentCampaign.id }}" class="sidebar-link" active-class="is-active">
                    {{ sidebarRoute.meta.sectionName }}
                </router-link>
                <ul class="sub-menu-list" v-if="sidebarRoute.children.length > 0">
                    <li v-for="childRoute in sidebarRoute.children" :key="childRoute.id">
                        <router-link :to="{ name: childRoute.name , params: { campaign_id: currentCampaign.id }}" class="sidebar-sub-link" active-class="is-active-submenu router-link-active">
                            {{ childRoute.meta.sectionName }} {{  childRoute.name }}
                        </router-link></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="base" v-if="((sidebarRoutes.length - 1)  === index)"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
```

you can see what when I try to print `childRoute.name`, it gives me the name and so that data is passed properly to the loop. then what is the issue here ? can someone help on the same ?

> [vue-router] Route with name 'activate.create_schedule' does not exist vue-router.esm.js:16

Comment: Add snippet with router configuration code....